# Pandas groupby with text items that should not be summed

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a test dataframe that looks as follows

```
test
Out[93]: 
  ID1 ID2  Value sometext1 sometext2
0   A   A     22     hello       bla
1   B   A     44     hello       bla
2   C   B     77     hello       bla
3   A   B     44     hello       bla
4   B   C     33     hello       bla
5   C   C     66     hello       bla


test_grouped=test.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).sum().reset_index()

test_grouped
Out[97]: 
  ID1 ID2  Value
0   A   A     22
1   A   B     44
2   B   A     44
3   B   C     33
4   C   B     77
5   C   C     66
```

My question is as follows:
Is there a way to get the values of sometext1 and sometext2 into test_grouped as well, without having to do a merge? Can I get this done directly with the groupby statement? The problem is obviously that sometext1 and sometext2 cannot be summed up. But in my case they will always contain the same value, so there will be no 'doubt' which value it should have, as it's always hello or bla.

Comment: Haven't really though about that. But makes totally sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know sometext1 and sometext 2 will always be the same for a given set of ID1 and ID2, then you can do the following.

```
test_grouped = test.groupby(['ID1','ID2','sometext1','sometext2']).sum().reset_index()
```

The above is the clear, easy solution, however it is not considered best practice because in the off chance that you are wrong (in that sometext1 and sometext2 can be different for the same set of ID1 and ID2), then you create duplicate entries for ID1 and ID2.  If this could be a problem, there are a few approaches you can take, depending on how you want to handle it, but I believe you'll need a merge in any case.  For instance, you could take the max of sometext1 for a given set of ID1 and ID2.  Or you could collect all values of sometext1 and store them as an array.